# Book Recommendation: Introduction to probability theory (including stochastic processes)

Tags: probability-theory, book-recommendation

I'm a first year undergraduate engineering student and we've got a course "Introduction to Probability Theory" which roughly covers the following topics:

> addition, multiplication, marginal and conditional probability, joint
>   probability, Baye’s theorem, random variables, probability mass
>   function, probability distribution function, moments and moments
>   generation function, binomial distribution, Poisson distribution,
>   exponential distribution, Gaussian /normal distribution, gamma
>   distribution, Chebyshev’s inequality, Schwartz inequality, q function,
>   random process, autocorrelation, auto covariance function, stationary
>   process, Erlang process, ergodic random process, Markov chain and
>   transitional probability, order of Markov chain, Chapman-Kolmogorov
>   equation, irreducible state, absorbing state, ergodoic chain, birth
>   and death process, Markovian queuing models

It would be very helpful if someone could suggest me a good book which covers all the above topics, because I searched on the net but no book seems to cover all the topics. Also our professor didn't suggest any book as such, but it would be helpful to have one because sometimes the professor's explanations can be confusing.

Comment: Have a look at "Probability Theory" bei Klenke

Comment: @Gibbs This question is asking for a book recommendation, I don't see why this is not a legitimate answer.

Comment: I would say is actually fine as a comment, not as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a mathematics student I've had courses on probability theory and stochastic processes, and for both of those courses used the book **Probability Theory and Random Processes** by Grimmet and Stirzaker. The explanations were clear, and I remember the exercises in the book to be quite challenging. At least in my experience back then, but I didn't have any previous experience with probability theory at that point.

Just had a look through the Contents, and it seems to cover pretty much all your topics (as far as I can tell from the contents).

Hope that helps.